# Array.filter do not work as expected and is shorten invaild code

Tags: javascript

I have the following code:

```js
var testList = [{
    "message": "Dieses Feld ist ein Pflichtfeld.",
    "element": {},
    "method": "required",
    "name": "email"
  },
  {
    "message": "Falscher Code!",
    "element": {},
    "method": "joeCode",
    "name": "code"
  }
];
var name = "code",
  method = "joeCodexcxxc";


testList = testList.filter(x => x.name !== name && x.method !== method);

console.log(testList);
```

i expected that the testlist is not touched because the "&& x.method !== method" is not given.
But the testList is shorten by "name": "code".
Whats wrong.
I still tested many brackets alternatives, without success.
Thx for any hint in advance.

Comment: what is the wrong? guess the array that has first element will be returned

Comment: Do you just want || instead of && ?

Comment: @william. Yes the first element will be returned. But isn't it wrong because there is no match tox => x.name !== name && x.method !== method?

Comment: testList[0].name !== "code" && testList[0].method !== "joeCodexcxxc", so that is correct to be filtered

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're most likely looking for an or gate `||` instead.

In this boolean expression,

```js
x.name !== name && x.method !== method
```

when `x` is the second element in your `testList`. It evaluates to

```js
"code" !== "code" && "joeCode" !== "joeCodexcxxc"
```

Which is `false && true`, which is `false` - and hence this object is filtered out.

Try with `||` instead-

```js
x.name !== name || x.method !== method
```

Or, to make the condition more human understandable, apply de-morgan's law

```js
!(x.name === name && x.method === method)
```

Comment: this made the deal: !(x.name === name && x.method === method) thx

Answer (score 0):

Your condition evaluates to false for the second object because name == "code", ergo we have false && true (which evaluates to false). You may be intending to use the || OR operator.